# How can I compare part of a string?

Tags: c#

I have a string "01-02" and I would like to compare it to another string "02-03-1234". Is there a simple way that I can compare if the first five characters of one string are equal to the first five of another string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `Substring` method to get part of the strings, and verify the length of the strings first unless you are completely sure that they are always at least five characters:

```
if (str1.Length >= 5 && str2.Length >= 5 && str1.Substring(0, 5) == str2.Substring(0, 5)) ........
```

Comment: This approach allocates temporary strings so might not be the best fit in performance critical scenarios.

Answer (score 29):

If your strings are at least 5 characters long, then `string.Compare` should work:

```
var match = string.Compare(str1, 0, str2, 0, 5) == 0;
```

Comment: Be aware that `string.Compare` uses the current culture to compare strings. For exact (and faster) string comparison use [string.CompareOrdinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es986b3k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 18):

```
bool startsWithFoo = "foobar".StartsWith( "foo" );
```

Comment: Note that `StartsWith` will compare all of one string to the same number of character in the other string, not the first five characters of one string to the first five characters of the other string.

Answer (score 4):

In .NetCore, or .Net framework with System.Memory nuget package:

```
str1.Length >= 5 && str2.Length >= 5 && str1.AsSpan(0, 5).SequenceEqual(str2.AsSpan(0, 5))
```

This is extremely heavily optimized, and will be the best performing of all the options here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (str1.Length >= 5 && 
    str2.StartsWith(str1.Substring(0, 5)))
{
    // Do what you please.....
}
```